# Stuck on RHCSA excersise task

Tags: linux, networking, redhat

so I am reading RHCSA & RHCE Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7: Training and Exam Preparation Guide book and am stuck on one of the tasks where I need to create a virtual bridge device. Here is the task:

In this exercise, you will create a virtual interface on host1 that will allow this host and server1 and server2, virtual
164guests that you will build in this chapter, to communicate directly with each other on the same 192.168.0 subnet using a
bridge. This interface will also be used by server1 and server2 during their build to access the RHEL7 installation files
on the FTP server that you configured in Exercise 6-5 on host1. This interface will be named br0 and will use the IP
assignments from em1 physical interface. These assignments are 192.168.0.100 IP address, 255.255.255.0 subnet
mask, and 192.168.0.1 gateway.
1. Change to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts directory and create a file called ifcfg-br0 in vi. Add the directives as
indicated below:

## cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts; vi ifcfg-br0

DEVICE=br0

BOOTPROTO=static

ONBOOT=yes

IPADDR=192.168.0.112

NETMASK=255.255.255.0

GATEWAY=192.168.0.1

TYPE=Bridge

NM_CONTROLLED=no

2. Edit the ifcfg-em1 file and set the following directives:

   ## vi ifcfg-em1

DEVICE=em1

TYPE=Ethernet

BRIDGE=br0

ONBOOT=yes

NM_CONTROLLED=no

HWADDR=D4:BE:D9:2E:2E:D9

So I created the 2 files with the required directives. The first thing that I suspect that I am getting wrong is the em1 device. This should probably be the name of my physical device (etc l0 or enp0s3). Or probably the issue is caused by the fact I am working on VirtualBox CentOS machine but there is the output I get from brctl show br0 command:

bridge name   bridge id     STP enabled interfaces

br0     8000.000000000000   no

As you can see the em1 is missing under the interfaces colon. And here is what I get with the same command for em1 device

bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces

em1     can't get info No such device

Can you please let me know what I am missing/doing wrong.

My apologies for the log post and that probably this is a newbie stuff for someone but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what I was able to find em1 has to be a virtual device(or I am completely wrong :D ). So I created it with next in line local IP (192.168.0.113) and it is pingable from my physical machine. But still, I am not able to attach the bridge (br0) device to that newly created one

Answer (score 0):

I passed RHCSA and I did the oficial course. Check this notes of mine. Maybe can help

```
    1  man teamd.conf
    2  lab teambridge setup
    3  nmcli connection add con-name team0 ifname team0 type team config '{"runner": {"name": "activebackup"}}'
    4  nmcli connection add con-name eno1-port1 ifname eno1 type team-slave master team0 
    5  nmcli connection add con-name eno2-port2 ifname eno2 type team-slave master team0 
    6  nmcli connection add con-name brteam0 type bridge ifname brteam0 
    7  nmcli device disconnect team0 
    8  nmcli device disconnect brteam0 
    9  systemctl stop NetworkManager.service 
   10  systemctl disable NetworkManager.service 
   11  cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
   12  vim ifcfg-team0 
   13  vim ifcfg-eno1-port1 
   14  vim ifcfg-eno2-port2 
   15  vim ifcfg-brteam0 
   16  systemctl restart network
   17  systemctl status network.service
   18  systemctl status network.service -l
   19  ip a
   20  systemctl status network.service -l
   21  reboot
   22  ip a
   23  cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
   24  vim ifcfg-brteam0 
   25  systemctl restart network
   26  systemctl status network.service -l
   27  reboot
   28  ip a
   29  ping -I brteam0 192.168.0.254
   30  lab teambridge grade
   31  systemctl restart network
   32  ping -I brteam0 192.168.0.254
   33  ping 192.168.0.254
   34  ping -I brteam0 192.168.0.254
   35  history 
   36  ping -I brteam0 192.168.0.254
```